# How to force a static library at a specific memory address

Tags: static-libraries, gnu, bare-metal, linker-flags, static-memory-allocation

I am building some applications that use a static library and I would want to force linker to put .text and .data sections of the static library (.a file) at specific addresses using GNU linker but I couldn't find a way how the linker script can be modified to force/put the libx.a at a specific address considering that this library has .text and .data sections.

Is there any way to do it?

I tried the below but linker does nothing:

```
    .text_libx :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*libx.a*(.text .text.*))
     } >FLASH_libx
```

where FLASH_libx is defined to a desired address.